# How to disable default gravity in unity for DOTS / ECS?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was following a demo as pointed out here: https://youtu.be/n_5RGdF7Doo?t=553

and noticed that my physics behaves different than in the video. I assume this might be because a different version of unity/physics packages is used.

So far i tried project settings/physics/gravity -> 0,0,0

as well as this:

```cs
Physics.gravity = Vector3.zero
```

in a initializer system. None of it seems to disable the default gravity. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Isnt ecs physics a whole new set of stuff whether its unity or havoc i think the ones you have tried are rhe monobehavior physics.  Cant say i messed with ecs physics myself.

Comment: Yes it is. However it copies some values into the DOTS space, which is why i tried to get rid of it by changing the project settings. i figured out how to fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after digging through the whole sample project i found the thing which causes the default gravity and how to get rid of it.

I added a Settings Gameobject to the scene and added a physics step configuration to it. Once i did that i no longer experienced default gravity effects.

[image]

Comment: Bloody hell! New Year is in 5 days, I'm learning DOTS, and this is yet another thing that tries to jump on the hastily leaving train of The Most Stupid Things I Learned This Year. Though now it wants to also bring a friend with it, because in the modern version of the Entities package you don't just ConvertToEntity, you do something else, involving a subscene and compile-time backing, which is described here for those who stumbles into the same problem: https://discussions.unity.com/t/convert-to-entity-script-is-not-there/257976/3 Legit I was unable to make it work in any other way. Thank you.